# Could not find implementation lookup function "class_getMethodImplementation" step in through ObjC method dispatch will not work

Tags: ios, objective-c

When building and running my iOS app from xcode, the following message appears in the terminal (iPhone 4s running 9.3.6).

> Could not find implementation lookup function
> "class_getMethodImplementation" step in through ObjC method dispatch
> will not work.

This message does not appear on my iPhone X on iOS 14.4.

What does this mean? I have been unable to find any documentation related to this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a warning from LLDB (the debugger) saying that it cannot find `class_getMethodImplementation` (a method in the Obj-C runtime), and that will prevent it from stepping through message dispatch.

Which may not help you much... *Why* LLDB cannot find that method is something you'll have to figure out, as is whether it is a significant warning.

You can find the LLDB error on line 726 of this [source](https://lldb.llvm.org/cpp_reference/AppleObjCTrampolineHandler_8cpp_source.html) file.

HTH